# How do I correctly setup flow js in a gatsby project?

Tags: babeljs, flowtype, gatsby

I searched for a way to use flow js in Gatsby but all that I found was [this](https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues/2784) discussion. Does anyone know a propper way to do setup flow?

Answer (score 2):

I ended up using one of my past configurations, namely:

**.babelrc**

```
{
  "presets": ["stage-2", "es2015", "stage-0", "react"],
  "plugins": [
    "typecheck",
    "syntax-flow",
    "transform-flow-strip-types",
    "add-module-exports"
  ]
}
```